# In Firefox how do you set the page a new tab opens to?

Tags: firefox, search-engines, adware, tabbed-browsing

I used to open a new tab and in the URL bar type whatever I wanted to google search. I had some adware toolbar that screwed with some settings and now when I open a new tab there's a search page and when I start typing it goes into the webpage's search field instead of the address bar.

What I want is to press ctrl+t and type in what I want to google and press enter. Now I have to take my hands off the keyboard and use the mouse to select the URL bar at the top. How can I fix this?

If my question doesn't make sense feel free to say so and I'll upload screen shots.
BTW I technically have Waterfox, not Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a new tab.
2. Copy and paste `about:config?filter=browser.newtab.url` into the address bar and press Enter.
3. Press "I'll be careful".
4. Right-click on the `browser.newtab.url` preference and click "Reset" to set it to the default new page tab (the speed dial). Alternatively, double-click on the `browser.newtab.url` preference and specify your own website (like a search engine) or `about:blank` for a black page.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the <kbd>F6</kbd>  button on your keyboard - the address bar is also a search bar.

Or, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> goes to the search box at the top right of the browser.